# Is there a name for storing data where each line either has a semi-colon or curly braces?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to understand how a Wordpress plugin works with data, when I pull it from MySQL it comes out like this:

```
a:1:{s:9:"home-team";a:6:{s:2:"id";s:9:"home-team";s:4:"slug";s:9:"home-team";s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:4:"name";s:9:"Home Team";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:4:"data";a:4:{s:7:"options";a:3:{s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-3892e2c3ad45e24dc7f47ff2ba880c33-2";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Chicago Bears";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";}s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-09fbd82bfa4142df6439c8e15d96dbfc-1";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:15:"New York Giants";s:5:"value";s:1:"2";}s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-7c7df972f933545b37c41ca249c686b4-1";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:15:"Oakland Raiders";s:5:"value";s:1:"3";}}s:8:"validate";a:1:{s:8:"required";a:3:{s:6:"active";s:1:"1";s:5:"value";s:4:"true";s:7:"message";s:22:"This Field is required";}}s:19:"conditional_display";a:2:{s:8:"relation";s:3:"AND";s:6:"custom";s:0:"";}s:16:"disabled_by_type";i:0;}}}
```

Is there a name for the way this is stored? To me it looks a little bit like JSON, but of course this is not JavaScript. Also, is there a way to clean it up easily (by using an online tool), so the first few lines would look like this:

```
a:1: {
  s:9:"home-team";
  a:6: {
    s:2:"id";
    s:9:"home-team";
    s:4:"slug";
    s:9:"home-team";
    s:4:"type";
    s:6:"select";
    s:4:"name";
```

etc.. etc.. etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the PHP serialize format.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Not sure how to get the formatted version exactly like you have it (but you could probably put that together easily), but here is another way to get an idea of what is in the serialized string:

```
$test_string= 'a:1:{s:9:"home-team";a:6:{s:2:"id";s:9:"home-team";s:4:"slug";s:9:"home-team";s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:4:"name";s:9:"Home Team";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:4:"data";a:4:{s:7:"options";a:3:{s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-3892e2c3ad45e24dc7f47ff2ba880c33-2";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Chicago Bears";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";}s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-09fbd82bfa4142df6439c8e15d96dbfc-1";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:15:"New York Giants";s:5:"value";s:1:"2";}s:60:"wpcf-fields-select-option-7c7df972f933545b37c41ca249c686b4-1";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:15:"Oakland Raiders";s:5:"value";s:1:"3";}}s:8:"validate";a:1:{s:8:"required";a:3:{s:6:"active";s:1:"1";s:5:"value";s:4:"true";s:7:"message";s:22:"This Field is required";}}s:19:"conditional_display";a:2:{s:8:"relation";s:3:"AND";s:6:"custom";s:0:"";}s:16:"disabled_by_type";i:0;}}}';
$unser = unserialize( $test_string);
print_r ( $unser );
```

Which will display:

```
Array
(
    [home-team] => Array
        (
            [id] => home-team
            [slug] => home-team
            [type] => select
            [name] => Home Team
            [description] => 
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [wpcf-fields-select-option-3892e2c3ad45e24dc7f47ff2ba880c33-2] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => Chicago Bears
                                    [value] => 1
                                )

                            [wpcf-fields-select-option-09fbd82bfa4142df6439c8e15d96dbfc-1] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => New York Giants
                                    [value] => 2
                                )

                            [wpcf-fields-select-option-7c7df972f933545b37c41ca249c686b4-1] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => Oakland Raiders
                                    [value] => 3
                                )

                        )

                    [validate] => Array
                        (
                            [required] => Array
                                (
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [value] => true
                                    [message] => This Field is required
                                )

                        )

                    [conditional_display] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => AND
                            [custom] => 
                        )

                    [disabled_by_type] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the way WordPress stores arrays and objects in the database. From the article [WordPress serializes options and meta for you](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3awdoTmCoIIk0J%3anacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/&lr=lang_es%7Clang_en%7Clang_pt&hl=es&tbs=lr%3alang_1es%7Clang_1en%7Clang_1pt&strip=1)

> In the most basic use case, [serialization](http://php.net/serialize) is a way to store arrays and objects directly in the database, which can only store numbers, text, and dates. Serialization takes an array and turns it into a serialized string. For example:
>
> ```
> $data = array( 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' );
> echo serialize( $data );
> // Result is a string we can unserialize into an array:
> // a:3:{i:0;s:5:"apple";i:1;s:6:"banana";i:2;s:6:"orange";}
> ```
>
> WordPress has a few helper functions that we use instead of `serialize()` and `unserialize()` — `maybe_serialize()` and `maybe_unserialize()`. The first only serializes data that needs to be serialized — arrays and objects — and the second only unserializes data that is already serialized. (We have a lot of handy functions like these.)

You mention *"when I pull it from MySQL it comes out like this"*, so you're probably not using the bundled functions to pull the data, like [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option), [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). Those functions take care of unserializing the data.

Worth noting that you should use a tool like [WordPress (and others) Search and Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to search/replace inside the database. As it takes care of replacing strings inside serialized data.

You cannot simply change:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:5:"apple";i:1;s:6:"banana";i:2;s:6:"orange";}
```

to

```
a:3:{i:0;s:5:"grapefruit";i:1;s:6:"banana";i:2;s:6:"orange";}
```

Because it should be `s:10:"grapefruit";`, being 10 the number of characters in the string.